# Where can I find Dell 1510 Wireless-N drivers?

Tags: 11.04, networking, dell

Where can I find Dell 1510 Wireless-N drivers for Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the 1510 is a Broadcom card.  You can get these drivers either by opening

```
jockey-gtk
```

or by running

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-*  && sudo modprobe wl
```

Answer (score 1):

For a quick broad fix for dell internet connections I use a USB wireless adapter. Cisco linksys adapter is recognised by many Linux distros as well as Windows. I also have a Realtek adapter on one of my laptops running Ultimate Edition Linux.

Hope this helps and saves some time for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to know is which chip set is used for WiFi. Run the following and you set what chip set is used.

lspci |grep Net